# Gallery Selected Position Animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-gallery

am trying to use this `myGallery.setSelection(5, true);` ([Gallery.setSelection(Position, Animate);](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection%28int,%20boolean%29)), which 5 is the requested position.

should this method animate the gallery till the new selected position is shown?? or just jumps to the selected position directly?

because when i use it, no animation happens !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set animation for on item selected listener. The animation will call only for selected gallery item.

```
myGallery.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        arg1.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.scale_img));
    }
});
```

this will help you.